# check image dimensions in javascript while upload

Tags: javascript, image, image-processing, upload

I've to upload image by checking its dimensions, only if that image fits into limits it'll be uploaded to the server else we should alert the user to change the image.

The question is how to check uploaded image dimension in javascript? Thanks.

Comment: You should always check these things server side, as javascript validation can be easily faked. Upload it, check it with php's getimagesize(), and then only save it if it fits into your limits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is impossible.

What you are asking is the dimensions of a file that you've requested the user to upload.

You are talking about a file upload, ie a file that is uploaded trough the  tag.

This file will only be read and uploaded to the server the moment the form is submitted.  So until you actually upload the file to the server, you have no access to the contents of the file.

The browser security model prevents access to this file...

You should verify this at the server side, and display an error message if they uploaded the wrong size of file.  This does mean that the file will need to be transferred and then rejected.

The only workarounds would mean to use plugins such as activeX objects or maybe flash, but then you are no longer using javascript...

Comment: Thanks. Now i came to know this is not possible. so one thing i could do, notice the user about what size/dimension of an image can be uploaded and use plugins like [Jcrop](http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/) to crop a selected image, but it still it uses a request to server, No other go!

Comment: In a project I worked on, we used a Java Applet to work with imanges. In fact, we had bandwidth restrictions and needed to be able to upload 100 or more images in one go, checking the type and size. This is the only way I see you can check on client side.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's no way to do this except with an URL. See this example how to do with an URL: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/ypkhP/1/)